# Want to return nothing when push a new object using save function in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have an query like :

```
 const { title,description } = request.body;
 const info = new Info({ title,description });
 info.save()
     .then(info => {
     console.log(info)
     })
     .catch(error => response.status(500).json({ message: "Server error created"})
);
```

When i console log info it return the new object. But i do not want to return nothing.

How can i do this?

Comment: You are already not returning the info object but a custom json message.

Comment: No, I  use return for checking the query return is a true response or not. I want to check `console.log(info)`. Here info is a json like object.But when i use save function, i do not want to return anything.